# How do I parse this JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm using a book API that returns the following

```
var _OLBookInfo = {
    "ISBN:234234234234234": {
        "bib_key": "ISBN:234234234234234", 
        "preview": "noview", 
        "preview_url": "http://openlibrary.org/b/adsfasdfa", 
        "info_url": "http://openlibrary.org/b/adsfasdf", 
        "details": {
            "publishers": [
                "W. H. sdafasdfasdf"
            ]
     }
};
```

How can I parse this with jQuery using the callback parameter of `$.get()`

Specifally, how do I get easy access to details -> publishers

**Update**

```
     $.post("/Home/LookupBook", { query: lookuptxt.val() },
               function (data) {
                   alert(data); //returns proper json data
                   alert(data.details.publishers[0]); // get erro saying details.publishers[0] is null
    }, 
   "json");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to parse a JSON string in JS. Simply see $.getJSON() method of jQuery.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

Example:

```
$.getJSON( url, data, function(response){
           alert(response['ISBN:234234234234234'].details.publishers[0]);
           } );
```

#### UPDATED: My bad -

I just saw that your call doesn't only return the JSON, but instead returns the JS file.

What you can do is to `eval()` the data returned from `$.get()`

```
$.get( url, data, funcCallback);
function funcCallback(data, status){
  eval(data);
  alert(_OLBookInfo['ISBN:234234234234234'].details.publisher[0]);
}
```

By the way, your JSON string is invalid. It has one missing curly brace at the back.

You can also try $.getScript():

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript

Answer (score 1):

Uhhh, JSON doesn't need to be parsed in JavaScript.  That's kinda the point in returning data in that format from the server.

Comment: JSON is a string when it travels, so yes, it does need to be parsed with JavaScript (or whatever language is going to use it).

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse JSON with JavaScript. What you provide in that example is a JavaScript statement, specifically an assignment statement. _OLBookInfo gets as its value that big hash of data.

Short answer: To make your example valid JSON, get rid of the `var _OLBookInfo =` part (and the trailing semicolon). JSON is just the object literal or array literal on its own. It's an ***expression***, not a ***statement***.

So the problem isn't with your JavaScript or jQuery, it's with the API. Whoever's API you're using mislead you if they said it returns *JSON*. If it's your own API, you can easily fix it to be valid JSON.

Comment: One thing that occurred to me -- maybe that API is supposed to return JavaScript. This is a common way to get around cross-domain limitations. For example, JSON-P works by returning JavaScript, so all you need is a script tag instead of an ajax call. If that's the case with your example, I can re-post an appropriate answer.

Comment: The API is supposed to return that javascript. I guess I thought it was JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback).